# MYSQL syntax delimiter and syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have tried to fix the syntax errors in the following but I can't see what on earth is wrong here:

```
DELIMITER =
CREATE TRIGGER trigs BEFORE UPDATE ON autoinc 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
DECLARE num_rows INTEGER; 
SELECT (*) INTO num_rows FROM autoinc;
IF num_rows >=3 THEN 
DELETE FROM autoinc LIMIT 1; 
END IF; 
END=
DELIMITER ;
```

The errors are:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to          your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) INTO num_rows FROM autoinc; IF num_rows >' at line 4

 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3 THEN
```

Can any please help me fix this?

Comment: `SELECT (*)` ? should't it be `SELECT count(*)`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it - but now it won't allow me to do a greater than or equal to comparison?

Comment: `DELETE FROM autoinc LIMIT 1; ` will not work. You can not do insert/update/delete on the same table where the trigger is executing.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments:

```
SELECT (*) AS num_rows ...
```

was probably meant to be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows ...
```

And the

```
IF num_rows >=3 THEN
```

breaks as you defined `=` as delimiter.

Use a delimiter that doesn't occur in your code, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER //
```

With these two changes things should work without syntax errors